# Blackberry - Navigate to other screen on clicking the SVG Element through Blackberry / J2me programme?

Tags: blackberry

I am having a SVG Rectangle Element on one screen, on click this element i have to navigate to other screen.

I want this anchor  element though Java code , and i dont want to use html tag code.

Please help in this point.

Answer (score 0):

use the 'a' element with xlink:href and target:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='100' height='1000'>
  <a  target='ncbi' title='t1' xlink:href='http://www.anywhere.org'>
    <rect x='1' y1='1' width='50' y2='50' style='fill:red;'/>
  </a>
</svg>
```